# Exit confirmation in Javascript with Telerik controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, onbeforeunload, confirm

I'm using Telerik controls for my project. On my page, there are some links to another page, several radtextboxes and a radbutton (it causes a postback). When the textbox values are changed, the button becomes enabled. Then, in my `window.onbeforeunload`, I check if the button is enabled or disabled. If it is enabled, then the confirm dialog appears. The code looks like this :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    var ClientGeneral_btnSave = $find('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>');
    if (ClientGeneral_btnSave.get_enabled() == true) {
    var message = 'You will lose unsaved data?';
    if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
       evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt) {
       evt.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
}
```

This code works well. When I close the tab, the confirm dialog appears. When I click on the links, it does. But, when I click on the btnSave itself, the dialog appears too, which is unsual. I want the btnSave NOT to cause `onbeforeunload` event

Please tell me how to do this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will fire onbeforeunload this if the btnSave posts back which it looks as if it is. Therefore you have a couple of choices

1. Prevent the btnSave from posting back if you don't need it to. Easiest way to do it is put this attribute in the asp:Button markup

   OnClientClick="return false"
2. Wire up a javaScript/jQuery method to disable the onbeforeunload event. I did this before by stashing an value in a hidden field and using this to signal that the onbeforeunload event should fire.

for instance

```
$('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').bind('click', function(e){

   $('#myHiddenFieldId').val('1');

});
```

and change your on beforeunload handler to check that the hidden field is not equal to 1 (make 0 the default i.e.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) { 

   if( $('#myHiddenFieldId').val() != '1')
   {
      //your logic here
   }

}
```

You could probably do something better by unbinding the onbeforeunload handler in the btnSave click event using JQuery rather than using a hidden field to override.

Option 2 can get fiddly though - so best of luck